# Is "We are running the red lights" right?

Tags: meaning

I read the following dialogue which I think is quite weird.

> - Look! Some people are running the red lights.
> - We should wait although others are breaking the rule.

I don't think the sentence "Some people are running the red lights" is correct. Suppose there is a scene: There is the red light, but we still run across the road without stopping. We can't say "we are running the red light", right? So how to say it in an authentic way?

Comment: I'd rephrase the second sentence: _We should wait, even if others are breaking the rule._ The word "although" isn't wrong per se, but there's an awkward ring to it.

Comment: what does "an awkward ring" mean?

Comment: It sounds "off". _Awkward_ is an oft-used term in grammar when a wording isn't wrong, but it could be made to flow in a more natural way. More on that [HERE](http://www.lsu.edu/faculty/jpullia/awkward.htm). As for _ring_, that's meaning #5 on [this page](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ring_28#ring_57).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Run a red light" is an idiomatic expression which means "to pass through an intersection while the traffic light is red without stopping."

So there is nothing "weird" in that dialogue and, as far as I can tell, using idiomatic English is pretty "authentic" as long as you correctly use it.

(Reference: "Dictionary of American Idioms" by R.A. Spears".)

The idiom is also used in British English along with "jumping a red light".  Discussion in the comments revealed that "breaking a red light" is used in Ireland.

Comment: "Running a red light" is an American idiom. The equivalent in British English is "breaking a red light".

Comment: Is there a online dictionary of American Idioms ?

Comment: @user, [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+a+red+light) is an excellent source where you can find almost all idioms.

Comment: @FrankH. Breaking?! That must be pretty expensive to replace every time! ;) Oh, you Brits... ;) Carlo, +1!

Comment: @Wendi, having an upvote from you is a great honour, thank you!

Comment: @FrankH.as a Brit I don't think I've ever heard "breaking a red light". My experience is that both "running" and "jumping" are common British usage, and FWIW [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=running+a+red+light%2Cbreaking+a+red+light%2C+jumping+a+red+light&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) for British English seems to agree.

Comment: @NigelHarper and WendiKidd, I stand corrected. On further investigation it seems "breaking a red light" is an Irish phenomenon - rather like myself :-) We have many English-language idioms that are Ireland-specific, but it didn't occur to me that this could be one of them!

Comment: Nigel, you're right. I haven't heard British people use  "breaking a red light". I've only heard "jumping a red light".