# Not stopping at a STOP sign

Tags: idioms, phrases, colloquial-language

Is there a street verb or an idiomatic saying that's used to say that a vehicle passed the (red traffic) light or a STOP sign without stopping?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [Is “We are running the red lights” right?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8550/is-we-are-running-the-red-lights-right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called **running** the sign, or the light. (Native AmE here.)

Comment: I knew it as **jumping** traffic lights

Comment: I've only ever heard "jumping" the light to mean going (starting from a stopped position) before the light turns green.

Comment: It's possible that the expression I knew was particular to the multilingual African country in which I grew up - where traffic lights were (and still are) known as robots.

Comment: Running is definitely the common AmE expression for someone who ignores a stop sign or red light entirely.  There's also the related "rolling stop" which is where you slow down significantly as you approach the intersection, but never come to a complete stop before proceeding through the intersection.

Comment: @PMV Where I'm from in a flyover state, we also refer to that as a "Califormia stop." I have no idea why, unless it just stems from the vague rural sense that people in more populated areas think the rules are beneath them.